# Instruments confusing "Growth" indication when calling mach_vm_dealocate

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, unreal-engine4, xcode-instruments

While profiling an application having set generations A, B and C I saw the following happen:

When just looking at Generation B (clicking the triangle and drilling down without clicking the arrow) I see the following:

[image: base generations view with drilldown]

Which is odd in my opinion because it boils down to a deallocate call which intuitively should be releasing memory.

What's more confusing is when I click on the arrow which presumably zooms into the delta between the generations the "Heaviest Stack trace" appears to be different altogether.

[image: arrow click on Generation B]

EDIT : Managed to find the same stack trace withing the Generation B section but still confused as to how a deallocation is allocating memory:

### [image: second stack trace]

What does this mean regarding growth for the call ending with `mach_vm_deallocate`?

Why does it show a different stack when I click on the arrow ?

Comment: I would love to learn the reason for this as well. Seems like a common element between your stack trace and mine is that there is a `thread_join` releasing a stack.